# Image processing: Floor plan - detecting rooms' borders (area) and room names' texts

Tags: image-processing

[image: here is a simple building floor plan]

Here is a simple building floor plan. I would like to derive the *rooms as (rectangular) components and the names of the rooms*. This is very common representation of building floor plans.

**The problem**

So far I could clean up the floor plan. However, only the walls are left as one component but I would like to derive the *rooms as rectangular components*. In the solution - The rooms may have polygonal shapes as well as rectangles with small rectangular components called circulation areas, corridors or an other function name... alternatively they could added to living room or any other near function. My Question is how to proceed from here?

**Code to start with**

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhl7.jpg"]
nsc = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .2}]];
m = MorphologicalTransform[nsc, {"Min", "Max"}]
```

**Cleaned up floor plan**

[image: Cleaned up floor plan]

**EDIT 1**

Some further information about the image.

The image contains 2 types of information.

1. The geometric
2. The Spatial

The Spatial information; it is important to abstract the room names for defining adjacency of spaces. The door and windows helps to define the adjacency matrix. The adjacency matrix with the geometric information can be used to calculate areas or boundaries. For example :
[image: Layout]

Comment: Your living room isn't a rectangle http://i.stack.imgur.com/AqOUt.png

Comment: Whats been left from the rectangles can be called circulation areas, corridors or an other function name... alternatively they could added to living room or any other near function. The solution image is sort of what I need.

Comment: In any case, the treatment of that degree of freedom should be specified in the question

Comment: I don't need exact solutions so they can rough n.p. Because the drawings are abstraction of real buildings and such representations you can tolerate that much of information. Edit the Q. as well.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**EDIT: Updated the algorithm, new part below**

Fun problem!

Ok, my first would be to find the room centers. This is relatively easy using a distance transform and geodesic erosion.

```
distTransform = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate@m];
ImageAdjust[distTransform]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The distance transform image contains for every pixel the distance to the closest wall. We're looking for the bright "peak" in the distance transform, i.e. the center of each room.

```
centerAreas = ImageDifference[
    GeodesicDilation[Image[ImageData[distTransform] - 10], 
    distTransform], distTransform]
```

**EDIT: The next part is new**

With this, we can use a watershed transform to find the rooms. The watershed transform (intuitively speaking) finds "basins" in a 3d landscape. We'll invert the distance transform image to turn the "peaks" into "basins" and use the room centers as markers:

```
watershed = 
 DeleteSmallComponents[
  DeleteBorderComponents[
   Binarize[
    Image[WatershedComponents[ColorNegate[distTransform], 
      centerAreas]]]], 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This segments the rooms quite well. Unfortunately, the watershed transform ignores the walls - the components we found are too big. But they're close enough that this simple "grow the room rectangle until it hits the wall"-algorithm finds the actual room areas:

```
rooms = ComponentMeasurements[watershed, "BoundingBox"];

Clear[growRect]
growRect[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := 
 Module[{checkRectEmpty, growSingleDirection, growSingleStep, cx, cy, 
   left, top, right, bottom, sizeEstimate, size},
  (
   {cx, cy} = Round[{x1 + x2, y1 + y2}/2];

   checkRectEmpty[{left_, top_, right_, bottom_}] := 
    Max[ImageValue[
       m, {cx - left ;; cx + right, cy - top ;; cy + bottom}]] == 0;
   growSingleDirection[size_, grow_] := 
    If[checkRectEmpty[size + grow], size + grow, size];
   growSingleStep[size_] := 
    Fold[growSingleDirection, size, IdentityMatrix[4]];

   sizeEstimate = 
    Abs[Round[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1}/2 - 20]];
   {left, top, right, bottom} = 
    FixedPoint[growSingleStep, sizeEstimate, 20];
   Rectangle[{cx - left, cy - top}, {cx + right, cy + bottom}]
   )]
```

Using this, all that's left is to display the results:

```
finalRectangles = growRect /@ rooms[[All, 2]];

feetAndInch[n_] := ToString[Round[n/12]] <> "'" <> ToString[Mod[n, 12]]
Show[m,
 Graphics[
  {
   finalRectangles[[ ;; ]] /. 
    rect : Rectangle[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] :>
     {
      {EdgeForm[Red], Transparent, rect},
      {Red, 
       Text[StringForm["`` x ``\n``", feetAndInch@(x2 - x1), 
         feetAndInch@(y2 - y1), (x2 - x1)*(y2 - y1)/(144.)], {x1 + x2,
           y1 + y2}/2]}
      }
   }]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or, using the original floor plan as background:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for putting a lot of thinking and effort! Thinning the walls might help improving it fit the rectangles. If you look at the bed rooms they are over divided. See my edit to Question.

Comment: +1 nice! Only works in mathematica 9 though.

Comment: @chris: I think the only new function is GeodesicDilation, right? You could get the same result using a combination of FixedPoint, Dilation and `MapThread[Min, {dilation, mask},2]`. Could be a lot slower, though.

Comment: I thing it is really great answer! One minor point needs to be considered is the _rectangle_ where eating is written as text. The rectangle should be smaller bounded by living room (most) east side and kitchens south walls.

Comment: @s.s.o: That rectangle is not a room at all. It's an artifact of the segmentation used. You could e.g. remove every rectangle that doesn't touch a wall e.g. 50% of its border. Implementation should be straightforward and is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: @nikie I'm fine with the solution. I'm using it as a part of larger problem. I just commented for completeness of the answer here.

Comment: Dear nikie,I have post a question same to this,http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/how-to-patch-fingerprint-ridges?noredirect=1#,would you take a try for me?I'll appreciate with you.

Comment: how to determine the windows and door

Answer (score 22):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhl7.jpg"];
nsc = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[img, {0, .2}]];
iD = ImageDimensions[img];
mWS = 70; (*Max window span*)
sLT = 5;(*Straight line tolerance*)
i4 = Thinning@(i1 = Closing[MorphologicalTransform[nsc, {"Min", "Max"}], 3])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let's find the endpoints for each door and window by using `HitMissTransform[]` .
We define some masks first:

```
k1 = ConstantArray[-1, 8];
v = {k1, {-1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1}};
h = {k1[[;; 4]], {-1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 0, 0}};
```

Now we find the candidate endpoints:

```
p = Position[ImageData@HitMissTransform[i4, #], 1] & /@ {v, Reverse@v, h, Reverse /@ h};
ListPlot[(Union @@ p) /. {a_, b_} -> {b, iD[[2]] - a}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we select only paired endpoints:

```
lin = Union[
 Select[Tuples[p[[1;;2]]], 0 < #[[1,1]] - #[[2,1]] < mWS && Abs[#[[1,2]] - #[[2,2]]] < sLT &],
 Select[Tuples[p[[3;;4]]], 0 < #[[1,2]] - #[[2,2]] < mWS && Abs[#[[1,1]] - #[[2,1]]] < sLT &]] /. 
                                     {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} -> {{b, iD[[2]] - a}, {d, iD[[2]] - c}};
Graphics[{Point@(Union @@ lin), Line@lin}, 
          PlotRange -> iD /. {x_, y_} -> {{1, x}, {1, y}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We finally "close" the doors and windows and use `MorphologicalComponents[]` to identify the rooms:

```
ColorNegate@ImageSubtract[img, Colorize@MorphologicalComponents@ Binarize@
            Erosion[Show[ColorNegate@i1, 
                   Graphics[Line@lin, PlotRange -> iD /. {x_, y_} -> {{1, x}, {1, y}}]], 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Graphics[Line@lin, 
 PlotRange -> ImageDimensions[i1] /. {x_, y_} -> {{1, x}, {1, y}}]` this pace of code is quite useful. If one needs to find the openings of buildings such as doors and windows, ect. It can also be used for adjacency of rooms.

Comment: Could you explain what k1, v and h is used for ? And do you think it is possible to separate living room and kitchen as components too. Because it has also sort of separator between them.

Comment: @s.s.o I don't think there is a clean way to separate the kitchen from the living room using this algorithm. I'm using the fact that a door or a window have a pair of right/left or up/down endpoints framing it. In fact the `k1, v and h`are the masks for the `HitMissTransform[]` used to identify those endpoints

Comment: @s.s.o You may however postprocess the areas afterwards to see if one of them isn't rectangular :)

Comment: Can anyone help me to convert it to matlab or any algorithm

Answer (score 5):

first of all, this is a very interesting problem.  I cannot provide you with a complete answer, however, if you apply

```
m = MorphologicalTransform[nsc, {"Max", "Min", "Max"}]
```

you can use

```
(mc = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@m]) // Colorize
```

to find a fair number of the rooms.  The expressions

```
lines = ImageLines[m, Method -> "RANSAC", MaxFeatures -> 15];
Show[m, Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Blue, Line /@ lines}]]
```

actually let you find the walls.  `ImageLines` has more options, so

```
lines = ImageLines[m, Method -> "Hough", "Segmented" -> True];
Show[m, Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Blue, Line /@ lines}]]
```

can restrict the search to walls inside the house.