# How to count the number of n-gons and line intersections in an image of a complete graph?

Tags: image-processing, counting

I would like to count the number of line intersections and number of n-gons in a complete graph (which forms a regular polygon). The only way I've come up with that would allow me to do both in *Mathematica* would be to:

1. Produce an image of the graph;
2. Apply some image processing tricks. I'm completely new to the world of image processing though.

Here is an example of a 10-graph:

```
n = 10;
firstCorners = Table[{Cos[2 Pi i], Sin[2 Pi i]}, {i, 0, 1, 1/n}];
lines = Subsets[firstCorners, {2}];
img = Image[Graphics[{Thick, Line[lines]}, ImageSize -> 350]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've got no idea how to proceed from here, everything I've tried has failed.

Comment: "_everything I've tried has failed._" What exactly have you tried? :)

Comment: I edited your question so `KSubsets` is not needed anymore.

Comment: @GenericUsrnme Do you want image processing solution or graph based solution with _Mathematica_. you may check http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t belisarius's solution for detecting intersection point using image processing solution. For 2d intersection detection algorithms you can check http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/graphics3d-finding-intersection-of-3d-objects-and-lines for references form this site.

Comment: Please note that for a given graph the number of intersections may vary with the choice of layout method. It's not an intrinsic property of a graph. Try for instance `Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 7, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8}]` and `Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 7, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8}, GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"]`. BTW Your graph can be generated simply by `CompleteGraph[10]`.

Comment: Ah, thanks!, @Öskå I'm mainly tried ImageCorner/Keypoints/Lines to try and generate a list for the number of intersections but I've only ever managed to get lists much larger than the real value when I've been testing with small n. For example with n=5 I get 2365 Lines, 1347 Corners when there is 10 and 10 respectively. Past this I have no idea what to do - I'm completely new to the Image Processing scene

Comment: @s.s.o Thank you, I will check these out tonight. I'm looking for any solution really, I'm thinking that an image process based one will be easier though since I want to be able to count the number of intersections (there's already a solution to the problem of counting the number of intersections in such a graph), the number of 3-gons, 4-gons etc. From my knowledge of graphs I don't think graphs will help much.

Comment: @Sjoerd I am aware of this, I'm restricting my attention to graphs where each node is placed with equal spacing around a circle. I decided not to use CompleteGraph for both aesthetics and because I was thinking that the big circles representing the nodes would interfere with any kind of "shape detection".

Comment: @GenericUsrnme How big could be `n`?

Comment: I don't think I'll be interested in anything greater than 30 or so, although I am aware that at some point (fairly close to 30 I'd think) that I'll be bottle necked by the resolution I'd need to be able to differentiate the different objects.

Comment: Related link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229611/speed-up-the-intersection-of-the-diagonals-of-a-regular-polygon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my humble attempt to solve this problem.

### - Counting the intersections:

Basically I'm just taking every points, I create linear functions out of them, and I search where they intersect.

```
n=10;
firstCorners=N[Table[{Cos[2 Pi i],Sin[2 Pi i]},{i,0,1,1/n}]];
lines=Subsets[firstCorners[[1;;n]],{2}];
slope[points_]:=Subtract@@(Last/@points)/Subtract@@(First/@points)
eq[points_,x_]:=Quiet@Simplify[slope[points]*x+Last@First@points-First@First@points*slope@points]
isInside[{x_,y_}]:=If[x^2+y^2<=1,True,False]
coor[{i_,j_}]:=
  If[Reduce[eq[lines[[i]],x]==eq[lines[[j]],x]&&-1<=x<=1]=!=False,
   With[{c=Reduce[x==Reduce[eq[lines[[i]],x]==eq[lines[[j]],x]&&-1<=x<=1][[2]]&&y==eq[lines[[j]],x]&&-1<=y<=1]},
     If[c=!=False&&isInside[{x,y}/.ToRules@c],{x,y}/.ToRules@c,{0,0}]],{0,0}]
subsets=Subsets[Range@Length@lines,{2}];
vertical=Flatten@Position[eq[lines[[#]],x]&/@Range@Length@lines,Indeterminate];
samePoint=Flatten@Position[lines,{firstCorners[[#]],_}|{_,firstCorners[[#]]},Infinity]&/@Range@(Length@firstCorners-1);
posSamePoint=Flatten@Position[subsets,#]&/@Flatten[Subsets[#,{2}]&/@samePoint,1]/.{}:>Sequence[];
subsets=Delete[subsets,posSamePoint];
subsets=Cases[subsets, Except[{Alternatives @@ vertical, _} | {_, Alternatives @@ vertical}]];
pts=DeleteDuplicates@Cases[coor@#&/@subsets,_List];//AbsoluteTiming
vpts=DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[Select[Table[With[{x=First@First@lines[[#]]},{x,eq[lines[[i]],x]}],{i,Delete[Range@Length@lines,List/@vertical]}],isInside@#&]&/@vertical,1];
allpts=If[OddQ@n,Cases[DeleteDuplicates@Round[Chop@Flatten[{pts,vpts,firstCorners},1],10^-10],Except[{0,0}]],DeleteDuplicates@Round[Chop@Flatten[{pts,vpts,firstCorners},1],10^-10]];
Length@allpts
```

> ```
> {0.491546, Null}
> 171
> ```

```
Graphics[{Thin, Line[lines], Red, PointSize@.015, Point@allpts}, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So that method works for at least `n = 30`.  Here is the result with `n = 20` (`n = 30` is quite messy):

> ```
> {11.589748, Null}
> 3861
> ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By running this piece of code for `n = Range[3, 10]` one can easily find that the number of intersections is equal to `{3, 5, 10, 19, 42, 57, 135, 171}`. Thus, searching for this sequence in [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B3%2C+5%2C+10%2C+19%2C+42%2C+57%2C+135%2C+171%7D) leads to [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A007569) with it's associated *Mathematica* code:

```
del[m_, n_] := If[Mod[n, m] == 0, 1, 0]; 
numberOfNodes[n_] := 
 If[n < 4, n, 
  n + Binomial[n, 4] + del[2, n] (-5 n^3 + 45 n^2 - 70 n + 24)/24 - 
   del[4, n] (3 n/2) + del[6, n] (-45 n^2 + 262 n)/6 + 
   del[12, n]*42 n + del[18, n]*60 n + del[24, n]*35 n - 
   del[30, n]*38 n - del[42, n]*82 n - del[60, n]*330 n - 
   del[84, n]*144 n - del[90, n]*96 n - del[120, n]*144 n - 
   del[210, n]*96 n]; 
numberOfNodes[#] & /@ Range[1, 20]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 19, 42, 57, 135, 171, 341, 313, 728, 771, 1380, 
>  1393, 2397, 1855, 3895, 3861}
> ```

Where `171` can be found for `n = 10` and `3861` for `n = 30`. In fact, they all seem to match with my code until `n = 30`. I haven't tried to go further due to computation time.

---

### - Counting the n-gons:

I did write a code for that part thanks to the code above, but it **only** works properly for **even** `n` smaller than `14`. For this reason I'm not keen to post it here unless requested.

But thanks to this code I found the following sequence of number of *n-gons*:

```
{0, 0, 1, 4, 11, 24, 50, 80, 154, 220}
```

[W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+4%2C+11%2C+24%2C+50%2C+80%2C+154%2C+220%7D) leading to [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A007678):

```
del[m_, n_] := If[Mod[n, m] == 0, 1, 0]; 
numberOfNGons[n_] := If[n < 3, 
  0, (n^4 - 6 n^3 + 23 n^2 - 42 n + 24)/24 + 
   del[2, n] (-5 n^3 + 42 n^2 - 40 n - 48)/48 - del[4, n] (3 n/4) + 
   del[6, n] (-53 n^2 + 310 n)/12 + del[12, n] (49 n/2) + 
   del[18, n]*32 n + del[24, n]*19 n - del[30, n]*36 n - 
   del[42, n]*50 n - del[60, n]*190 n - del[84, n]*78 n - 
   del[90, n]*48 n - del[120, n]*78 n - del[210, n]*48 n]; 
numberOfNGons[#] & /@ Range@20
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 1, 4, 11, 24, 50, 80, 154, 220, 375, 444, 781, 952, 1456, 
>  1696, 2500, 2466, 4029, 4500}
> ```

Finally, for `n = 12` I have indeed `444` n-gons and I can then generate this kind of figure:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

More information about the theory can be found [here](http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf) and [here](http://thales.math.uqam.ca/~rowland/investigations/polygons.html).

Comment: Thanks! I remember seeing that paper before but I could never find it again. This is really helpful though

Comment: @GenericUsrnme You are welcome :) That was quite a few times ago but I had fun with that :D You can consider accepting it if you like :)

Answer (score 5):

*(This should be a comment, but it got too long. In a nutshell: Don't use image processing for this. It's a computational geometry problem, and you should solve it as such. Look up line sweep algorithms, if you're worried about computational complexity. But for n<=30, a simple brute-force algorithm might be fast enough.)*

Getting an image processing solution is pretty easy. You already have `img`, just use

```
colors = MorphologicalComponents[DeleteBorderComponents[Binarize[img]]];
```

to assign a unique index to every connected component of white pixels in `img`. So `Max[img]` is the total number of connected component, and `Colorize[colors]` gives an image where each connected component is colored differently:

[image]

Unfortunately, *this gives you the wrong result*. If you look closely in the image above, there are a few single-pixel "components" that are really artifacts from the drawing algorithm. We can highlight them:

```
smallComponents = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
   DeleteBorderComponents[Binarize[img]], {"Centroid", 
    "Area"}, #2 < 5 &];    
HighlightImage[Darker@Darker@Colorize[colors], 
 smallComponents[[All, 2, 1]]]
```

[image]

So this is really only useful if you want to create pretty pictures or if a rough estimate is good enough.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to provide references to any relevant literature on computational geometry? I'm relatively new to the computational end of things here