# How to patch fingerprint ridges

Tags: image-processing, image

I get a fingerprint:

[image]

But as you see,there are some place is discontinuous,such as:

[image]

The question is how to patch the discontinuous line according its gradient?The only one thing that I can think it may be helpful is use `Closing` or `Dilation`in transverse orient,but the effect is very bad

[image]
[image]

Could anybody can give some advice for this?

Comment: In literature I think it's called fingerprint ridges... In _Mathematica_ docs you may search GradientOrientationFilter and example/VisualizeTheGradientDirection. Also the answer of @belisarius is forth for this Q might be helpful using hit and miss transform... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t

Comment: Do you have a greyscale image from which your binary image is derived? It would be better to use greyscale rather than binary as your starting point.

Comment: But ... are those discontinuities a "feature" or a "bug"? I mean ... aren't they in the real thing (finger)?

Comment: I have the same thought as belisarius. What you are attempting may just be introducing artifacts into image and falsifying the fingerprint.

Comment: @m_goldberg @belisarius is forth I am surprised that you will think so, in fact, the image-processing with the nature of the forgery, isn't it? And this is an ordinary picture, it comes from http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thinning.html?q=Thinning.  I just do some little broken thing on it.`Mathemaica` is only responsible for how to achieve the purpose, as for me is not intended to be used to do illegal things, I think this should be the law to restrict. Science and technology is a double-edged sword,which is know by everyone.And it should not be discussed in here.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell I'm have not it.Actually it comes from reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thinning.html?q=Thinning. I just do some little broken thing on it.But converting it into a greyscale is easy I think.And I try another again with grayscale just,which cannot bring a good result.Would you help me take a try?

Comment: I did not intend to imply that you were doing anything shady. I only wanted to point out that, since fingerprints may naturally show gaps in their ridges, you might not be repairing a defect but worsening the image's fidelity.

Comment: @m_goldberg Orz..Sorry for my poor English to failure understanding you.Actually I don't care the image's fidelity.And the problem I meet isn't patch fingerprint ridges.If I post the original question,it'll be very prolix.So I refine the core of the difficulties I encountered with the documentation's image.Could you help me to take a try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be difficult to do for a human, as it would require very strict definitions of a gap. I will present a method to get lines which will come very close to representing the gaps.

First we'll set up a table of all of the white pixels

```
a = [IMAGE]
b = ImageValuePositions[a, White];
```

b is just:

```
ListPlot[b]
```

[image: finger]

Now we want to calculate each points distance from every other point:

```
findDist[p1_, p2_] := EuclideanDistance[p1, p2];
AbsoluteTiming[
  dists = Table[{i, j, findDist[b[[i]], b[[j]]] }, 
    {i, 1, Length[b]}, {j, 1, Length[b] }]]

(*63s on an i5 4570*)
```

Now we'll filter (or *cluster*) for pixels close to other pixels, then dump these results generate a graph:

```
s1 = Select[Flatten[dists, 1], #[[3]] > 0 && #[[3]] < 3 &];
sa = SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ s1[[All, {1, 2}]]];
adj = AdjacencyGraph[sa, DirectedEdges -> True];
```

adj:

[image: adjacency graph]

Each one of these 'fingers' represents a string(line/curve) of pixels, these are what we will use later on.

Separate these 'fingers' of pixels (pardon the horrible variable name):

```
numbers = Table[ConnectedComponents[adj][[i]], 
  {i, 1,Length@ConnectedComponents[adj]}];
```

Now we want to calculate the largest and smallest points on each of these 'fingers' (these are the start/stop of these segments)

```
largestPointArr = 
  Table[{#, Total[b[[#]]]} & /@   numbers[[i]], {i, 1, 
    Length@numbers}];
largestPts = (TakeLargestBy[#, #[[2]] &, 1] & /@ largestPointArr)[[All, 1, 1]];

smallestPointArr = 
  Table[{#, Total[b[[#]]]} & /@   numbers[[i]], {i, 1, 
    Length@numbers}];
smallestPts = (TakeSmallestBy[#, #[[2]] &, 1] & /@ largestPointArr)[[All, 1, 1]];
```

Now that we have the largest and smallest points, we want to create a curve that extends from these points. In order to generate a curve we need to have trailing and leading points from these largest/smallest points

This function grabs adjoining pixels to the leader or contra-leader of the 'finger'

```
findCurvePts[p_, 1] := Flatten[AdjacencyList[adj, #] & /@ Flatten[p]]
findCurvePts[p_, n_] := 
  findCurvePts[(AdjacencyList[adj, #] & /@ Flatten[p]), n - 1]
```

Now we're going to fit a curve to the smallest and largest points using their neighbors.

```
largestPtsAndCurves = 
  Flatten@Table[{largestPts[[i]] -> 
      Fit[b[[#]] & /@ findCurvePts[{largestPts[[i]]}, 6], 
      {1, x, x^2}, x]}, {i, 1, Length@largestPts}];

smallestPtsAndCurces = 
  Flatten@Table[{smallestPts[[i]] -> 
      Fit[b[[#]] & /@ findCurvePts[{smallestPts[[i]]}, 6], 
      {1, x, x^2}, x]}, {i, 1, Length@smallestPts}];
```

Each of the largest and smallest pts/curve variables contain the index of the large / small pixel correspond to a function

Because we now have functions which can predict where the next pixels should be, we can plug in the domain from the smallest points into our functions and compare the ranges

Here we plug and chug, only keeping connections where the predicted range is within 3 units of the actual range:

```
cadidates = 
  Select[Flatten[
    Table[{largestPts[[i]], smallestPts[[j]], 
      b[[smallestPts[[j]]]][[2]] - (largestPts[[i]] /. largestPtsAndCurves)
        /. x -> b[[smallestPts[[j]]]][[1]]}, 
    {i, 1, Length@largestPts}, {j, 1, Length@smallestPts}], 1], 
  Abs[#[[3]]] < 3 &];

smallCadidates = 
  Select[Flatten[
    Table[{smallestPts[[i]], largestPts[[j]], 
      b[[largestPts[[j]]]][[2]] - (smallestPts[[i]] /. smallestPtsAndCurces)
      /.  x -> b[[largestPts[[j]]]][[1]]}, 
    {i, 1, Length@smallestPts}, {j, 1, Length@largestPts}], 1], 
  Abs[#[[3]]] < 3 &];
```

Now lets see what we got- lets plot all of b(the white pixels) with the candidate connections:

```
Show[ListPlot[{b}], 
 Graphics[{Line[{b[[#[[1]]]], b[[#[[2]]]]}] & /@ 
    cadidates, {Pink, Point[b[[#[[1]]]]]} & /@ 
    cadidates, {Blue, Point[b[[#[[2]]]]]} & /@ cadidates}]]

Show[ListPlot[{b}], 
 Graphics[{Line[{b[[#[[1]]]], b[[#[[2]]]]}] & /@ 
    smallCadidates, {Pink, Point[b[[#[[1]]]]]} & /@ 
    smallCadidates, {Blue, Point[b[[#[[2]]]]]} & /@ smallCadidates}]]
```

[image: see what we got]

What a mess! We are in need of some elimination- all of the candidates can be eliminated if they cross over other points- the "gaps" never cross points.

Now make some lines and remove leading and ending points:

```
bigLines = Line[{b[[#[[1]]]], b[[#[[2]]]]}] & /@ cadidates;
smallLines = Line[{b[[#[[1]]]], b[[#[[2]]]]}] & /@ smallCadidates;

filteredPts = 
  Complement[b, b[[#]] & /@ Join[smallestPts, largestPts]];
```

Now we calculate the distance from every line, to every other point- only qualify a line if the distance to other points is >= 1

```
 AbsoluteTiming[
  smallPointDist = 
     ParallelTable[{i, 
       RegionDistance[smallLines[[i]], filteredPts[[j]]]}, 
       {i, 1, Length@smallLines}, {j, 1, Length@filteredPts}]];

winningSmall = Select[Flatten[
   Table[ MinimalBy[smallPointDist[[i]], #[[2]] &, 1], 
   {i, 1, Length@smallLines}], 1], #[[2]] >= 1 &]

AbsoluteTiming[
  largePointDist = 
   ParallelTable[{i, 
     RegionDistance[bigLines[[i]], filteredPts[[j]]]}, 
     {i, 1, Length@bigLines}, {j, 1, Length@filteredPts}]];

winningLarge = 
 Select[Flatten[
   Table[ MinimalBy[largePointDist[[i]], #[[2]] &, 1], 
   {i, 1, Length@bigLines}], 1], #[[2]] >= 1 &]
```

Here's what we have:

```
Show[ListPlot[{b}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, bigLines[[#]]}] & /@ winningLarge[[All, 1]], 
 Graphics[{Blue, Thick, smallLines[[#]]}] & /@ winningSmall[[All, 1]]]
```

[image: final]

Here it is having some trouble with the reflection:

[image: reflect]

Here is the transposition:

[image]

I would love to hear ways to improve this!

Comment: What a crazy!Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: link [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109870/share-a-method-to-patch-the-discontinuous-line-in-a-image)