# Share a method to patch the discontinuous line in a image

Tags: image-processing

Similar to this post which I have posted before([How to patch fingerprint ridges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/how-to-patch-fingerprint-ridges)),Its solution's level higher than my expectation.So cost my these days to research this.Now I'm glad to share my fruit in here,You can use this code to produce a broken heart line.

```
SetAttributes[RandomDrop, HoldFirst]
RandomDrop[list_, n_] := 
 Module[{pre, temp}, 
  Do[pre = RandomInteger[{1, Length[list]}]; temp = RandomInteger[25];
    If[pre + temp <= Length[list], 
    list = Drop[list, {pre, pre + temp}], Continue[]], n]; list]

MakeBrokenHeart[n_] := 
 Module[{sortpos, graph, pos}, 
  graph = ContourPlot[((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 - (1.3 x)^2 y^3 ==
      0, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 200]; 
  pos = PixelValuePositions[graph // Binarize // ColorNegate, 1]; 
  sortpos = pos[[Last@FindShortestTour[pos]]]; 
  Binarize@ImageRotate@
    ImagePad[
     ImageCrop@Image[SparseArray[RandomDrop[sortpos, n] -> 1]], 5]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have here is called a [matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in graph theory: You want to connect a set of nodes so that

- each node is connected to exactly to one edge,
- and some cost function over the edges is minimized.

I can't find a built-in function for solving matching problems, but it's not hard to convert it to a linear programming problem.

First, I'll find all the endpoints:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWNUV.png"]    
endPoints = 
  PixelValuePositions[MorphologicalTransform[img, "EndPoints"], 1];    
endPointIndices = Range[Length[endPoints]];
```

Then I make a list of edges that connect each node to it's 4 closest neighbors (you could also start with a complete graph and get the same result in the end; this just keeps the search space smaller):

```
near = Nearest[endPoints -> endPointIndices];    
allEdges = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Table[
     edge[Sort[{i, j}]], {i, endPointIndices}, {j, 
      Rest@near[endPoints[[i]], 5]}];
```

Now `allEdges` contains a list of the form `edge[{1, 3}], edge[{1, 5}], edge[{1, 6}]...`, connecting each node to its neighbors:

```
HighlightImage[img, allEdges /. edge[idx_] :> Line[endPoints[[idx]]]]
```

[image]

Next I want a rough direction for each endpoint. There are a lot of ways to do this. I'll simply select, for each end point, the points in the same arc that are closer than 20 pixels and take the mean of those points:

```
components = Image@MorphologicalComponents[img];
endPointNeighbors = Table[
   pointsInSameComponent = 
    PixelValuePositions[components, PixelValue[components, pt]];
   N@Mean[Select[pointsInSameComponent, Norm[# - pt] < 20 &]]
   , {pt, endPoints}];
```

`endPointNeighbors[[i]]` now contains the center of the neighbors on the same arc as `endpoint[[i]]`:

```
HighlightImage[img, 
 Table[Arrow[{endPointNeighbors[[i]], endPoints[[i]]}], {i, 
   endPointIndices}]]
```

[image]

So that gives me the "direction" from each endpoint:

```
endPointDirection[i_] := 
 Normalize[endPoints[[i]] - endPointNeighbors[[i]]]
```

and I can define a "cost" for each edge:

```
edgeCost[edge[{i_, j_}]] := 
 Norm[endPoints[[i]] - endPoints[[j]]] + 
  10*endPointDirection[i].endPointDirection[j]
```

(I've used a weighted sum of the distance of the end points and the scalar product of the edge directions. You can read it as "if the lines point in the same direction, make the edge 10 pixels longer; if the lines point in opposite directions, make it 10 pixels shorter". So edges pointing in the right direction are cheaper. You could probably come up with a smarter cost function.)

So far so well. Now I'll use `FindMinimum` to find a set of edges that minimizes the cost, and assigns exactly one edge to each end point.

I'll use variables `connected[{i, j}]`, where `connected[{i,j}] == 1` means that endpoints `i` and `j` are connected, so I have the variables:

```
allVariables = allEdges /. edge[idx__] :> connected[idx];
```

and the total cost of all connected edges:

```
cost = Total[
   allEdges /. e : edge[{i_, j_}] :> N@edgeCost[e]*connected[{i, j}]];
```

The `connected[{i,j}]`-variables should all be between 0 and 1 (in fact, the result will always be 0 or 1, exactly):

```
connectedRange = allEdges /. edge[idx__] :> 0 <= connected[idx] <= 1;
```

And I want each end point to be connected to exactly one edge:

```
singleEdge = Table[
   Total[Cases[allEdges, 
      edge[idx_] /; MemberQ[idx, i] :> connected[idx]]] == 1,
   {i, endPointIndices}];
```

Optimization:

```
{totalCost, solution} = 
  FindMinimum[Flatten[{cost, connectedRange, singleEdge}], 
   allVariables];
```

yields a `solution` that looks like this:

> connected[{1, 3}] -> 1., connected[{1, 5}] -> 0., 
>   connected[{1, 6}] -> 0., connected[{1, 9}] -> 0., 
>   connected[{2, 4}] -> 1.

So we can pick the edges where `connected` is 1:

```
connectedEdges = Pick[allEdges, Round[allVariables /. solution], 1];
```

and display them:

```
HighlightImage[img, 
 connectedEdges /. edge[idx_] :> Line[endPoints[[idx]]]]
```

[image]

The algorithm is guaranteed to connect every end point to exactly one edge (and will therefore fail if the number of end points is odd), and it will always have the lowest possible cost (it's a linear programming problem, so `FindMinimum` is fast and guaranteed to find the optimal solution`). But the quality of the final matching will depend on the edge cost function, of course.

So for example, if I only minimize the distance between edges, I'll get this matching:

[image]

The total distance of all the edges is shorter, so the algorithm is correct. Or in other words: You'll probably have to play with the cost function a little to get the results you want.

Comment: +1，Amazing.Especially your `edgeCost`  remind me that I have omited a important information about its intersection angle.But still have a little advice to your `endPointDirection`.The `mediod` is a little farfetched to do this I think.And my `NearstPoint` is intend to do it.I'm look forward you can make a more wonderful `endPointDirection`,then your solution will be suitable for more complicated cases.But anyway I have deeply moving to your current project.

Comment: @yode: Done. As I said, I was just looking for a quick&dirty estimate good enough for the optimization, not for a perfect tangent vector.

Answer (score 4):

So this is my broken heart image.

```
{pic1, pic2, pic3} = MakeBrokenHeart /@ {4, 6, 7};
pic = Thinning@ImageAdd[pic1, ImageResize[pic2, Scaled[4/5]], 
  ImageResize[pic3, Scaled[2/3]]]
```

[image]

Get thoes discontinuity points and define a function to find some endpoints(Before the `NearstPoint`,I have try a `GradientOrientationFilter`,But the precision is too low,If you can use it proficiently to judge the orientation of the edge pixel,you can put your method in following).

```
pos = ImageValuePositions[MorphologicalTransform[pic, "EndPoints"], 
   1];
NearstPoint[pic_, start_, n_] := 
 Module[{list = ImageValuePositions[Binarize[pic], 1], cap = {start}},
  Do[AppendTo[cap, First@Nearest[Complement[list, cap], Last@cap]], 
   n]; cap]
```

Use half line to highligh the orientation.

```
HighlightImage[pic, 
 HalfLine[{TrimmedMean[NearstPoint[pic, #, 10]], #}] & /@ pos]
```

[image]

Match the point every pair

```
ResampleLine[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, n_] := 
 Transpose[{Subdivide[a, c, n], Subdivide[b, d, n]}]
pointpair = 
  Function[p, {p, 
     First@MinimalBy[Complement[pos, {p}], 
       Total[RegionDistance[
           HalfLine[{TrimmedMean[NearstPoint[pic, p, 10]], p}], 
           ResampleLine[p, #, 7]] + 
          RegionDistance[
           HalfLine[{TrimmedMean[NearstPoint[pic, #, 10]], #}], 
           ResampleLine[p, #, 7]]] &]}] /@ pos;
```

The result is like this(My version is 10.4.0.The `HighlightImage` have some diffrence than before)

```
HighlightImage[pic, {White, 
  DiscretizeGraphics /@ (BezierCurve[{Last@
         NearstPoint[pic, #, 5], #, #2, 
        Last@NearstPoint[pic, #2, 5]}] & @@@ pointpair)}]
```

[image]

As you see,there are some blemish in this solution

[image]

Of course,I make a imperfect example on purpose to show some problem still in this solution.But it can work well in some case like

[image]

And make the method more practical in other curve.It cost my some times but fail to perfect it.If you are interesting this.Improve it please.Also I have some place don't really satisfied,especially the part of match these point pairs.