# How to connect some separate components with shortest total length line

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks

Maybe [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111460/how-to-make-a-disconnected-graph-to-be-1-edge-connectedbut-not-2-edge-connected) is too hard. So I try to make a simple version to research.

Simulating a simple graph than that post.

```
SeedRandom[2]
p = RandomReal[1, {20, 2}];
sortPoint[p_] := 
 Module[{order = Last[FindShortestTour[p]]}, 
  If[RandomReal[] < .5, p[[Rest[order]]], p[[order]]]]
Graphics[line = Line /@ sortPoint /@ FindClusters[p, 5]]
```

[image]

Make it to be a graph

```
rule = Dispatch[MapIndexed[Rule[#, First[#2]] &, p]];
g = Graph[
  Catenate[Developer`PartitionMap[UndirectedEdge @@ # &, #, 2, 1] & /@
     Level[line /. rule, {2}]], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Reverse /@ Normal[rule]]
```

[image]

Add some additional edges between components each other

```
gLast = Fold[
  GraphUnion[#, #2, VertexCoordinates -> Reverse /@ Normal[rule], 
    VertexLabels -> "Name"] &, g, 
  Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ Tuples[#]] & /@ 
   Subsets[ConnectedComponents[g], {2}]]
```

[image]

To make sure we can select these edge we want,we should make some essential variables.

```
var = Rule[addEdge @@ #, #] & /@ 
   Complement[EdgeList@gLast, EdgeList@g];
weightRule = 
  Rule[#, EuclideanDistance @@ (# /. Reverse /@ Normal[rule])] & /@ 
   Complement[EdgeList@gLast, EdgeList@g];
var2 = connectQ @@@ Keys[var];
```

But obviously the [method of nikie's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109899/21532) don't give integer always.

```
sol = Last[
   FindMinimum[{(Values[var] /. weightRule).var2, 
     And @@ Thread[0 <= var2 <= 1] && 
      And @@ Thread[
        Total /@ 
          Function[ind, Select[ind, MemberQ[var2, #] &]] /@ 
           Apply[connectQ, 
            IncidenceList[gLast, #] & /@ 
             ConnectedComponents[g], {2}] == 1]}, var2]];
```

As we see the result,we get some 0.5,neither 0 nor 1.But when we give a constraint such `Element[var2, Integers]`.It will give some error information.

```
Values[sol] // Counts
```

> <|1. -> 1, 0. -> 153, 0.5 -> 3|>

I think if we can solve this equation then the process in following become easy.Of course,if you have another smart solution,I'll glad to know.:)

---

ps: The result picture maybe like following.Of course,this is just an approximate guess.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will help:

```
cc = ConnectedComponents@g;
pts = Map[{#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]} &, cc, {2}];
pre = First@MinimalBy[#, Last] & /@ 
   Apply[{#1[[1]] <-> #2[[1]], Norm[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]]} &, 
    Tuples /@ Subsets[pts, {2}], {2}];

spt = EdgeList@
   FindSpanningTree[
    CompleteGraph[Length@cc, EdgeWeight -> pre[[;; , 2]]]];

res = Extract[pre, 
   First@Position[
       UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[Range@Length@cc, {2}], #] & /@ spt];

res[[;; , 2]] // Total
HighlightGraph[g~EdgeAdd~res[[;; , 1]], res[[;; , 1]]]
```

Let me explain how this code works:

1. Our goal is to find a shortest connection between point groups (`ConnectedComponents`). So the first thing we should do is to find out the shortest distance between each tuple.

   The first five lines of my code is doing this job: Find out `ConnectedComponents`, then determine those points' position. Finally create list `pre` by calculating the distance between each tuple of points in each tuple of `ConnectedComponents`  and single out the shortest connection in each tuple of `ConnectedComponents`.
2. Find the shortest path that can connect this whole graph together.

   If we want to get the shortest connection, then it must be a tree, `FindSpanningTree` will do the job~ Check the code generating `spt`.
3. Take the result and reform them into the form we would love to see.

   Take the edges' in `spt` and reform them back to the edges in the original graph. Check the code generating `res`.
4. Presentation

   Quite simple~ Check the rest of the code~

The result will be as follow:

[image: the result is just as you wanted]

the value shown in the graph is the minimum distance.

---

## UPDATE

A version if you want to use it everywhere! The only thing you should do is paste this code everywhere and set the input graph's name to `gorig`!

```
l = VertexList@gorig;
coor = PropertyValue[{gorig, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ l;
g = Graph[Range@Length@l, EdgeList@gorig /. Thread[l -> Range@Length@l], 
   VertexCoordinates -> coor];

cc = ConnectedComponents@g;
pts = Map[{#, PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]} &, cc, {2}];
pre = First@MinimalBy[#, Last] & /@ 
   Apply[{#1[[1]] <-> #2[[1]], Norm[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]]} &, 
    Tuples /@ Subsets[pts, {2}], {2}];
spt = EdgeList@
   FindSpanningTree[
    CompleteGraph[Length@cc, EdgeWeight -> pre[[;; , 2]]]];
res = Extract[pre, 
   First@Position[
       UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[Range@Length@cc, {2}], #] & /@ spt];
res[[;; , 2]] // Total
HighlightGraph[g~EdgeAdd~res[[;; , 1]], res[[;; , 1]]]
```

Comment: I suppose this code works for the harder post too~ :)

Comment: Thanks!Good luck in the examination. :)

Comment: NOOOOOOO!!! The exam has been cancelled cause someone comporomised the test material!!!

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Comment: I have to say that your `FindSpanningTree` replace my `FindMinimum` is a wonderful idea.

Comment: I will update my post now......

Comment: Edited~ this time the code is much more direct and clear.

Comment: Thanks very much.And I make a little change in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118163/21532) last night.I hope you don't mind. :) And have you received the message I send you in chat room?

Comment: Nope......I didn't received any message still...... BTW, I don't mind at all~ see WTFPL~ BTW2: I think your question is all of high quality~ Really inspiring!

Comment: Well,I'm glad to acquire such hight assessment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41022/discussion-between-wjx-and-yode).

Comment: I started the chatroom :)

Answer (score 0):

Original method:

```
ConnectSeparateGraphCost[graph_] := 
 Module[{rule, cc, minWeightInCom, allMinEdge, spanTreeEdge, 
   completeGraph}, 
  rule = Dispatch[
    MapThread[Rule, {VertexList[graph], GraphEmbedding[graph]}]];
  cc = ConnectedComponents[graph];
  minWeightInCom = 
   First@MinimalBy[#, Last] & /@ 
    Map[{#, EuclideanDistance @@ (# /. rule)} &, 
     Tuples /@ Subsets[cc, {2}], {2}];
  allMinEdge = UndirectedEdge @@@ First /@ minWeightInCom;
  spanTreeEdge = 
   EdgeList[
    FindSpanningTree[
     completeGraph = 
      CompleteGraph[Length@cc, EdgeWeight -> Last /@ minWeightInCom]]];
  EdgeAdd[graph, 
   allMinEdge[[EdgeIndex[completeGraph, #] & /@ spanTreeEdge]]]]
```

Update the efficacy:

```
ConnectSeparateGraph[graph_] := 
 Module[{rule, pts, f, var1, var2, nearePoint, completeGraph}, 
  rule = Dispatch[
    MapThread[Rule, {VertexList[graph], GraphEmbedding[graph]}]];
  pts = WeaklyConnectedComponents[graph] /. rule;
  f = Nearest /@ Most[pts];
  var2 = Drop[pts, #] & /@ Range[Length[pts] - 1];
  var1 = MapThread[Catenate /@ # /@ #2 &, {f, var2}];
  nearePoint = 
   Catenate[
    Map[First[MinimalBy[#, EuclideanDistance @@ # &]] &, 
     Flatten[{var1, var2}, List /@ {2, 3, 4, 1, 5}], {2}]];
  completeGraph = 
   CompleteGraph[Length[pts], 
    EdgeWeight -> EuclideanDistance @@@ nearePoint];
  EdgeAdd[graph, 
   UndirectedEdge @@@ (nearePoint[[EdgeIndex[completeGraph, #] & /@ 
         EdgeList[FindSpanningTree[completeGraph]]]] /. 
      Reverse /@ Normal[rule])]]
```

When the separate component is `50`:

```
g=(Uncompress@*FromCharacterCode@*Flatten@*(ImageData[#1, "Byte"] &)@*
   Import)["https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/02/18/58a8035aae255.png"];

ConnectSeparateGraphCost[g]; // AbsoluteTiming(*old method*)
ConnectSeparateGraph[g]; // AbsoluteTiming(*updated method*)
ConnectSeparateGraphCost[g] == ConnectSeparateGraph[g]
```

> {2.18698, Null}
>
> {0.329665, Null}
>
> True