# How to find length of wall sizes

Tags: image-processing

I have room size calculated from mathematica. Now i have to classify between walls from the image[image]

My second output should be from the source image, i have to classify similar walls based on thickness and categorize as External wall 1, Interior wall2 along with their lengths. I am new to mathematica and any help will be appreciated

source image: [image]

I have achieved the canvas layout based on

```
rooms = ComponentMeasurements[watershed, "BoundingBox"];

Clear[growRect]
growRect[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := 
 Module[{checkRectEmpty, growSingleDirection, growSingleStep, cx, cy, 
   left, top, right, bottom, sizeEstimate, size},
  (
   {cx, cy} = Round[{x1 + x2, y1 + y2}/2];

   checkRectEmpty[{left_, top_, right_, bottom_}] := 
    Max[ImageValue[
       m, {cx - left ;; cx + right, cy - top ;; cy + bottom}]] == 0;
   growSingleDirection[size_, grow_] := 
    If[checkRectEmpty[size + grow], size + grow, size];
   growSingleStep[size_] := 
    Fold[growSingleDirection, size, IdentityMatrix[4]];

   sizeEstimate = 
    Abs[Round[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1}/2 - 20]];
   {left, top, right, bottom} = 
    FixedPoint[growSingleStep, sizeEstimate, 20];
   Rectangle[{cx - left, cy - top}, {cx + right, cy + bottom}]
   )]
```

Please let me know how can i enhance further to achieve the sizes for walls similar to room sizes

Comment: What were your code attempts so far? How do you calculate room sizes as you reference? These sorts of things, like your code attempts, go a long way towards helping others to help answer your question! Welcome to mma.SE :)

Comment: @CATrevillian  - I have calculated room sizes based on reference provided in [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t)

Comment: You should add this referenced link to your question in an edit, and provide the code you used to do what you have done so-far. It would be far better to do this and would improve your chances of having the question looked at for people to answer it. As it stands, I am not sure what or how you have done what you have done, and have no way to answer. Others may vote to close this also if it does not appear you have done something with Mathematica. Links and updates provided in the comments can be easily buried and become non-visible a result.

Comment: I have edited. Thanks

Comment: Does mathematica support detecting wall sizes?