# Mathematica 9 code won't work in Mathematica 12

Tags: mathematical-optimization, compatibility

It's just plain simple copy paste from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/image-processing-floor-plan-detecting-rooms-borders-area-and-room-names-t/19550#19550?newreg=e4cb64356a2744599f67b51db14fde7e)

here is my [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/b1ac1482-fa99-427e-be38-c13559d5ae0c)

Hope someone can get right directions why output goes wrong after watershed was applied

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you use `growRect ` in the line `finalRectangles = growRect /@ rooms[[All, 2]];` before it is defined? At least it seems to work fine for me when I define `growRect` first...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher you can see it(issue) earlier, after watershed was applied. It doesn't process whole image, but return part of it

Comment: Ah, I see. I am afraid that I am not sufficiently knowledgeable in this regard. But please state precisely in your question what does not work as expected. People here just hate to be forced to make guesses. (You can _edit_ your quest.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher my bad =) anyway thanks